# Roteiro para deploy Pipenv (Python)

Tags: python, django

Olá,
na empresa onde trabalho as regras de firewall não permitem que servidores destinados a intranet tenham acesso à web. Dessa forma, trabalhar com `venvs`, onde as dependências são instaladas com `pipenv install`, não é possível.

Existe alguma forma de fazer o deploy de todo o `environment` para que os módulos nele existentes funcionem sem necessidade de instalação no servidor?

Caso negativo, como empacoto todo o `venv` de forma que o projeto funcione quando for desempacotado no servidor?

Estou trabalhando com Python 3.6 e Django 2.0.

Grato